# How to use parameter from URL in Lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

We want to create a Cloud Page that dynamically changes content in the page according to a URL parameter. Users will visit the page directly, we won't send them to the page from email.

What I did:

Created DealerDE with some data:

```
ID|Name|Phone
1 |Joe |1234
2 |Dan |5678
```

Created cloud page and used the Lookup function successfully manually, `%%=Lookup('DealerDE','Name','ID',1)=%%`

Output: `My name is Joe and my phone is 1234`

My question:

I want that according to the URL parameter `example.com/?id=2` the page will show the Name and the Phone from the DE: `My name is Dan and my phone is 5678`
What needs to be done i Lookup query to make it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two functions in AMPscript that let you retrieve the parameters sent by the request message.

1. QueryParameter - Only usable for GET-parameters (suitable for your use case)
2. RequestParameter - Usable for GET- and POST-parameters (also suitable for your use case)

So your code would look like this:

```
%%=Lookup('DealerDE','Name','ID', RequestParameter('id'))=%%
```

**Related documentation:**

- [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm)
- [QueryParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/queryparameter.htm)

Comment: Thank you!

Follow up question: if this parameter doesn't exist in the URL, can I show default value? instead of ```example.com/?id=1``` the user entered ```example.com/```

Comment: For that use case you need to use IF-statements. I suggest reading the ampscript syntax guide which shows how to do so.